# Handle JSON structure with Pyspark

Tags: json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark and trying to read JSON file of the format below into a spark dataframe. This is the format of my JSON

"elements": [

```
Q4
{
Name:ABC,
Language:English,
Age:45,
Title:SWE

},

Q5
{
Name:DEF,
Language:English,
Age:60
Title: Engineer
},

Q6
{
Name:HIJ,
Language:English,
Age:57,
Title:
}
```

]
I want the output to be

```
Name | Language | Age | Title     
ABC  | English  | 45  |   SWE    

DEF  | English  | 60  | Engineer  

HIJ  | English  | 57  |   Null
```

How do I achieve this with pyspark?

Answer (score 2):

Please try using

```
df=spark.read.json()
```

to read the file. It will convert you data into the dataframe format. You may need to chose JSON element if you need the document inside the element.

--Edited part, If you want to use hard code string, pls refer spark doc:
Example content from spark document.

```
sc = spark.sparkContext
jsonStrings = ['{"name":"Yin","address":{"city":"Columbus","state":"Ohio"}}']
otherPeopleRDD = sc.parallelize(jsonStrings)
otherPeople = spark.read.json(otherPeopleRDD)
otherPeople.show()
# +---------------+----+
# |        address|name|
# +---------------+----+
# |[Columbus,Ohio]| Yin|
# +---------------+----+
```

--Edit2 With your example but I picked only the required data to create dataframe here. I hope, this will work for you.

```
    import os
    import sys
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    import json
    from pyspark.sql import Row

    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate()



    json_doc1='{"elements": {"Q4":{"Name":"ABC","Language":"English","Age":45,"Title":"SWE"},"Q5": {"Name":"DEF","Language":"English","Age":60,"Title": "Engineer"}}}'
    test=json.loads(json_doc1)
    data1=test['elements'].values()
        print (data1)

    #rddd1= sc.parallelize()
    df1=spark.createDataFrame(Row(**x) for x in data1)


    df1.show()


+---+--------+----+--------+
|Age|Language|Name|   Title|
+---+--------+----+--------+
| 60| English| DEF|Engineer|
| 45| English| ABC|     SWE|
+---+--------+----+--------+
```

Thanks,
Manu

Comment: Thanks.From your example, if I wanted to make  Name, City and State as columns on my dataframe and remove the address struct , how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Hey first thing you need to do is..Correct the JSON document. The JSON you have given here is not correct. You can easily validate the JSON using online tools.

Comment: It's always good to update if your work is done. If not, then also, you should update.